Sklearn module missing and unsure what to use instead?
I'm currently following this guide https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rainfall-prediction-using-machine-learning-python/
However. I am getting this error for the following lines of code.
for i in range(3):

    models[i].fit(X, Y)


    print(f'{models[i]} : ')


    train_preds = models[i].predict_proba(X) 

    print('Training Accuracy : ', metrics.roc_auc_score(Y, train_preds[:,1]))


    val_preds = models[i].predict_proba(X_val) 

    print('Validation Accuracy : ', metrics.roc_auc_score(Y_val, val_preds[:,1]))

    print()



    metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(models[2], X_val, Y_val)

    plt.show()

I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'plot_confusion_matrix'. Did you mean: 'pair_confusion_matrix'?"
Apparently, the plot confusion matrix was deprecated, but I am unsure of what to do now as I do need this graph.
I hope you can help!!
Have tried looking through the documentation, but cannot find what is replacing this old function.

This question is similar to: ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes this was the case. I am now with the problem that I am getting this error:  File ...... line 125, in  models[i].fit(X, Y) ValueError: Input X contains NaN. LogisticRegression does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively.

You should try to use sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplayas mentionned here: ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Here is the code I currently have:
features = df.drop(['Number', 'Rainfall'], axis=1)
target = df.Rainfall
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(features,target,test_size=0.2,stratify=target,random_state=2)
.......
ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator(models[2], X_val, Y_val)
plt.show()`
I am getting these errors and am unsure what is wrong:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ...... line 125, in 
models[i].fit(X, Y)
ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
LogisticRegression does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively.

Im not quite sure whats happening here. Is there a way for me to clean out these NAN data. In line 125 it says the following:  models[i].fit(X, Y)
print(f'{models[i]} : ')




train_preds = models[i].predict_proba(X) 

print('Training Accuracy : ', metrics.roc_auc_score(Y, train_preds[:,1]))


You should maybe try to understand why you got NaN values. If df is your pandas dataframe, you can use df.dropna() to clean these NaN values. Look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html
